# Not sure why the variable isn't becoming defined in my if / elif statement

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently taking a 100 day python course and I am at the BMI calculator part 2. Here is the code I created:

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))
BMI = round(weight / height ** 2, 1)
if BMI < 18.5:
    category = underweight
    if 18.5 >= BMI <= 25:
     category = normal_weight
    elif 25 >= BMI <= 30:
     category = slightly_overweight
    elif 30 >= BMI <= 35:
     category = obese
    elif BMI > 35:
     category = clinically_obese
print("Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are " +category+ ".")
```

This is the error I am getting :

```
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    print("Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are " +category+ ".")
NameError: name 'category' is not defined
➜
```

Comment: If the first `if` statement does not fire, then `category` is not defined.

Comment: It looks like your code is incomplete, please double check it and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code is identically indented as you have shown then a BMI over 18.5 will result in no category being set.
I am also assuming this is not your whole code as none of the categories that you want to print are actually defined.

For it to work you need indent it correctly (I also added an `elif` for the second case):

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))
BMI = round(weight / height ** 2, 1)
if BMI < 18.5:
    category = underweight
elif 18.5 >= BMI <= 25:
    category = normal_weight
elif 25 >= BMI <= 30:
    category = slightly_overweight
elif 30 >= BMI <= 35:
    category = obese
elif BMI > 35:
    category = clinically_obese
print("Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are " +category+ ".")
```

For the code to be executable you can just wrap each of your categories in `"` --> e.g.: `category = "slightly_overweight"`

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and did this and for some reason, obese isn't defined now, the other weights are defined but it stops at obese. With the code above.

Comment: What do you mean with "stops at obese"? Do you get an error? Did you define `obese`? We can't see the code where the other categories are set. Or do you want to have the categories as strings?

Comment: What do you mean with "stops at obese"? Do you get an error? Did you define `obese`? We can't see the code where the other categories are set. Or do you want to have the categories as strings?

Comment: Oh I see, I have 2 variables, category and the weight term, I need to figure out how to give them both value.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    category = underweight
NameError: name 'underweight' is not defined

Comment: Whatever the BMI falls under, the weigh term isn't defined.

Comment: In the code that you have in your question the variables that you want to print as `category` are not set. In order to make it work you need to define them first or instead define the string that you want to output such as: `category = "underweight"`

Comment: Oh wow thank you! I needed to correct my indentation and use the quotations, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. I edited my original answer to include the solution. Would be nice to have it accepted :)